# How to install/use Oraclize on Windows 10?

Tags: oracles, external-api

I wanna get data from external data(web or just text files) to my smart contract.

I found how to install and use the external data!

But all the data was for Linux.

like, sudo apt-get install npm blah blah

But I wanna develop my smart contract on windows environment.

anybody knows where can i get that information?

or could you let me know how to install and use Oraclize on Windows?

Comment: The environment in which the smart contracts are executed is Ethereum Virtual Machine. The contracts are not programs running of your pc as any other windows software. Also, you do not install oraclize in your computer, you just use functions of the oraclize's contract in your own contract.

I recommend you to go to the basics of ethereum. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, there is no way of installing Oraclize, as it's what some may refer to as a "Service in the Cloud". There are various tools you can use for it such as the ethereum-bridge, which may need to have its dependencies installed using its package manager. In the case of Oraclize, most tools are made with NodeJS, and require that to be installed along with its package manager `npm`. The procedures for installing and using these tools, are normally unified and OS-agnostic, although the way to use them, is different than day-to-day use on Windows, and require you to use your command prompt.